# Printing the nth word starting from the nth line

Tags: java

```
int lines = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
String word = null;

while((word =br.readLine()) != null){
  lines++;
  if(lines == 29){
    System.out.println(word); 
    //Write code to count the word and print the value
    while(sc.hasNext() && count <= 1000){
      count++;
      String value = sc.next();

      if (count == 20){
        System.out.print(value + ",");
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

I want to print the nth word starting  from the nth line. In my case, starting counting the words from line 29 and printing the word number 3 again starting from line 29.
How can I do this?

Comment: [l.split(' ')[3] for i, l in enumerate(open('file')) if i == 29] oh....

Answer (score 2):

```
while((word =br.readLine()) != null)
{
    lines++;
    if(lines == n)
    {
        String[] words = lines.split(" ");
        String wordYouSearch = words[n - 1];
        System.out.println(wordYouSearch);
        break;
    }
}
```